# Filemanager that asks for sudo rights when it needs it

Tags: nautilus, sudo, filemanager, nemo

On my Mac I can copy files using the Finder, and if the destination folder has a different owner, a window pops up and asks for credentials.

On Ubuntu or Linux Mint I don't see anything like that. Then I need to start Nautilus or Nemo from the commandline using sudo rights. I would like to get a popup whenever it is needed.

So I use Nemo (or Nautilus) just like normal and do whatever I need to do. I close it and open it another time, and at one point or another I need to copy a folder to /opt. Then it refuses because /opt is owned by root. A window pops up and asks for my sudo password or for a user that has sudo rights if the specific user has no sudo rights. The folder is copied to /opt and that's it.

Is is possible to let it work like this, with an extension or something? Do other filemanagers have this option?

Comment: With Nemo, you can just open a directory in a new window with root privileges by right-clicking on the folder and selecting "open as root".

Comment: @ByteCommander - you may add this as answer if you want the points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nemo already has the functionality to open a folder in a new Window with root permissions. You just have to right-click on a folder icon and select "open as root" in its context menu.

[image: Screenshot of Nemo with folder context menu]
<sub>Image source: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4PwLsyex1Bo/UEqi2kD9h7I/AAAAAAAAANU/iHXfQRKdMfw/s1600/nemo-file-manager-open-as-root.png</sub>

When you click on that option, you will get the gksu-popup asking for your admin account's password. After correctly entering this, a fresh second window of Nemo opens at the selected location.